# Azure Data Factory - Copy files to a list of folders based on json config file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use Azure Data Factory to read a json file and copy files based on the config it contains.

The json file:

```
{
    "FolderConfig": [
     {   
        "Source": "/pub/example",
        "Destination": "/FOL1"
     },
     {
        "Source": "/pub/example",
        "Destination": "/FOL2"
     }
    ]
}
```

The idea is to loop over the objects in FolderConfig and do a foreach on them.

The foreach would then copy files from source to destination

I tried using a Lookup activity with 'Source DataSet' set to the json file and this gives the following output:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "FolderConfig": [
                {
                    "Source": "/pub/example1",
                    "Destination": "/FOL1"
                },
                {
                    "Source": "/pub/example2",
                    "Destination": "/FOL2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "integrationDebugRuntime1",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 2
    }
}
```

I then use this output in the ForEach activity with 'Items' set to
'@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].FolderConfig'

The ForEach iterates over the FolderConfig array and here I use a 'Copy Data' activity.

In the 'Copy Data' activity I am able to specify the source using dynamic content:
[image]

However for the destination sink I can't seem to use dynamic content from the ForEach item

[image]

Does somebody have an idea on how to specify a variable destination?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

First: 'items' in the ForEach activity should be like this:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].FolderConfig
```

Second:click 'open' button at sink(Azure blob storage)
[image]

Final:add this dynamic content

```
@item().Destination
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the input!
I didn't know I could use this in the sink dataset but it works! I did have to remove the forward slash in front of the destination folder in the json file.